# FCM push notification does not update view when called in receiveMessage

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I followed this [tutorial: Push Notifications with Angular 6 + Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://medium.com/@a.adendrata/push-notifications-with-angular-6-firebase-cloud-massaging-dbfb5fbc0eeb)

Everything works fine. I can see my notifications pushed when I use another browser. I need to add my `onInit()` function here:

```py
receiveMessage() { 
    this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe( 
    (payload) => { 
    console.log("new message received. ", payload); 
    this.currentMessage.next(payload); 
    this.navBar.onInit();
    }) 
}
```

so it can refresh the notification list and the Notifications length.

I'm using a Spring Boot backend and I only need the List of my notification to be refreshed. Only the NavBar component needs a refresh.

I'm using FCM to generate tokens for users so I can send notifications to other users when some update is made in my DB (Postgres).

I can't even store the value of the payload outside that function. event the `CurrentMessage.next()` is not able to keep the value of the payload outside the `receiveMessage()` function.

When I `console.log` the `CurrentMessage` the value is `null` outside the `receiveMessage()` function. Is there a way to refresh my list?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted basically to have the list of unread notifications from my BackEnd:

```js
 
 ngOnInit() {
// ......... some other code
  $("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', ".get-notification",  () =>{
        
        if($('.get-notification').text() != "" && $('.get-notification').text() != ""+this.listNotifLength){
            this.GetUnreadNotification();
           // console.log($('.get-notification').text());
            $('.notification').removeClass('get-notification');
          }
       
        });
   }
 
 GetUnreadNotification() {
 //....... some other code
  $('.notification').addClass('get-notification');
                $('.get-notification').text(this.listNotifLength );
                
                
                }
```

```html
                            <span class="notification" *ngIf="listNotifLength != -1" >{{listNotifLength}}</span>
```

It's not the best way to do it but it actually works. If anyone has a better proposition that would be great.
don't forget to call this.GetUnreadNotification() inside the  this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
      (payload) => { .... })